# Is md5 value language dependent?

Tags: javascript, java

If I generate `md5` of a file in java and javascript -Will both the values be same?
I have to generate `md5` in javascript and send it to the server and the server matches it. I am getting a hash mismatch error.

Actually, I need 'base64 encoded 128-bit MD5 digest' to send to S3 using javascript.

Thanks

Comment: They should definitely be the same.

Comment: share your code where you are getting  mismatch errro ?

Comment: one possibility is that you're not sending it properly

Comment: they should be the same. if you show the code generating it and the code validating it, we might help in finding the problem

Comment: How do you compare the hashes? Maybe it's the common "how to compare strings" - issue?

Comment: The issue in my case was, one of the hashing was the client(from Js) and one was in the server-side(Java). So, the two hash was not the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`md5` is the hashing algorithm, It is language independent. as long as the input to the algorithm is same it will generate same hash

Comment: * scratches hair * a high rep users that places a comment as answer?

Comment: @KarelG Well, it *is* the answer. There is not really more to it, is it?

Comment: @Jigar: "as long as the input to the algorithm is same it should generate same hash" - I would even go so far to say "it **must** generate the same hash". Otherwise it would be broken and useless.

Comment: @Fildor If you ask me, user P.J.Meisch has approached the question more correctly by [placing a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43110370/is-md5-value-language-dependent/43110386?noredirect=1#comment73301367_43110370) to the OP's question.

Comment: @KarelG Actually, I think the Question is incomplete. Jigar answers the Question "Will both the values be same?" adequately , IMHO. But the actual problem stated may not have anything to do with this, but OP is not giving enough information to tell. So, while the length of the answer may seem to be better suited to be a comment, it still answers the question based on the info given. Just my 2 cents. Personally I consider the Q not fully answerable in that an answer to the formulated question will not necessarily solve the problem. But anyway - this discussion may better be suited for meta.

Comment: @KarelG I don't really get your logic. Answers should be left as answers, not as comments.

Answer (score 0):

MD5 is just an hashing algorithm and hence can be implemented in any language. Result will be the same, as long as you don't make any mistake in the implementation.

Some areas to take care of, while implementing in different languages, which could unintentionally introduce errors in implementation, could be: range/Truncating/promotion of integer values, operators precedence etc.

Answer (score 0):

> NO. MD5 is language independent.

But as I understood you are creating the hash code from one computer and reading it using another, which may cause into a charset chaos. Make sure you are using the same charset *UTF-8* recommended.
And also I found this helpful, try using this without storing the hash in your database.

```
public static String MD5(String md5) {
        try {
            java.security.MessageDigest md = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            byte[] array = md.digest(md5.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
                sb.append(Integer.toHexString((array[i] & 0xFF) | 0x100).substring(1, 3));
            }
            return sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
```